# Xcode 11: Huge Increase in ipa size compared to Xcode 10 archive size

Tags: archive, ipa, ios13, xcode11, xcode10.2

I have been trying to archive a binary file for App Store submission from **Xcode 11** GM Seed 1. It has increased the binary size by more than **60 MB** compared to build generated in **Xcode 10.2** (Though there is no any single change in image resource assets, not added any new framework)

Can you please update me what can be the cause of this huge size increase issue?

Comment: What about GM 2/Stable?

Comment: have you got any reason or workaround for this? we are also facing similar issue.

Comment: any solution? same issue we are facing

Comment: Compare assets.car file in both ipa (just rename to .zip and extract), it is highly possible that due to increase of assets.car file ipa size increased. After uploading binary you can check download size to different device, hopefully it will be same as before.
Another thing you can check is share extension assets. whether its using redundant assets or not